# How do I scroll/drag element inside parent with overflow visible?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of posts that is being filtered when I press a year. I want to make the years scrollable and draggable. How do I do this? I want thee years to be overflowing from the parent like the image below.

I tried slick.js and swiper but the amount of a slide has to be declared while the year supposed to be dynamically generated from cms.

Please dont mind the years being doubled.

[image: desired result]

```css
.m-year__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 68px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.m-year__container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 500%;
}

.m-year__item {
  opacity: .15;
  transition: 250ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.m-year__item.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-year__wrapper">
  <div class="m-year__container">
    <div class="m-year__item is-active">
      2021 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item is-active">
      2021 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2016 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2016 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2015 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2015 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2014 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2014 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2013 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2013 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2009 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      2009 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      1995 </div>
    <div class="m-year__item">
      1995 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a native scroll with css? set a width to the wrapper with overflow auto

Comment: @Huangism thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately doing so or overflow scroll will override the overflow visible and the year outside the wrapper wont be visible